# ¿Puedo acceder a las celdas de un GridPane como si fuera un array?

Tags: java, array, javafx

Sé que existe el método add(Node, column, row) de la clase GridPane, que sirve para añadir un nodo a una celda en concreto, lo que busco es lo contrario, como un get(column, row) o algo similar.

Comment: Hola si estas requiriendo una opinión, te sugiero revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta, es cierto que antes era innecesariamente enrevesada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que lo que quiero hacer no puede hacerse de una forma tan sencilla.

He encontrado un post en inglés que me ha sido de ayuda y plantea el mismo problema, lo dejo aquí por si a alguien pueda servirle también.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655024/javafx-gridpane-retrieve-specific-cell-content/20656861

Se plantean varias soluciones al problema, la que voy a llevar yo a cabo consiste en crear una clase que herede de GridPane, y tenga una lista como atributo en la cual habrá que almacenar los nodos que queramos representar, y estos nodos tendrán que tener los atributos row y column, la clase que hereda de GridPane implementa un método creado por nosotros getChild(int row, int column) que buscará en la lista si algún nodo contiene esta coordenada y si es así lo retornará.

En resumen, parece ser que JavaFX no ofrece una solución a un problema tan simple y hay que plantear una solución por nosotros mismos.